# Will default-constructing an integer array zero-initialize it?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, default-constructor

If I have a structure with an array member, and I explicitly call the default constructor of the array in the structure's constructor, will the elements get default-constructed? (In the case of an integer array, this would mean getting zero-initialized).

```
struct S
{
    S() : array() {}

    int array[SIZE];
};

...

S s;
// is s.array zero-initialized?
```

A quick test with gcc suggests that this is the case, but I wanted to confirm that I can rely on this behaviour.

(I have noticed that if I don't explicitly default-construct the array in the structure constructor, the array elements have random values.)

Comment: Any particular reason you aren't using `std::vector`?

Comment: @AJG85: Yes. If I allocate an array of 100000 of these structures, I would like that to result in a single allocation of 100000*SIZE bytes, rather than a single allocation of 100000*sizeof(int*) bytes plus 100000 allocations of SIZE bytes. (On the other hand, I *could* be a little more C++-y by using `boost::array` (or `std::array` in C++0x)).

Comment: @High: Your mental model of `std::vector<int>` is completely wrong. It has a constant overhead of about 12 bytes plus some overhead on the free-store.

Comment: Fair enough although the overhead of vector is not that considerable, I was going to say `std::array` at first but it's not fully supported by all compilers yet.

Comment: Also, is `S s;` at namespace scope (global variable) or at function scope (local variable)? Because if it is at namespace scope, the array will be initialized with zeros even if you omit the parenthesis from the member initializer list. Aren't C++ initialization rules fun? :)

Comment: @FredOv the global / local scope is an important difference, might be a good comment for Oli's answer

Comment: @FredOverflow: Can you explain how my mental model of `std::vector` is completely wrong? If I use `vector<int>` instead of an array in my structure, and in the constructor initialize the vector to have `SIZE` elements, and then declare an array of 100000 `S` structures, will that not result in one allocation of `100000*sizeof(vector<int>)` bytes, and 100000 dynamic allocations of `SIZE*sizeof(int)` bytes? As opposed to a single allocation of `100000*SIZE*sizeof(int)` if I used the array?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes (highlighting mine):

> (C++03 8.5)
>
> **To value-initialize an object of type T means:**
>
> - if T is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
> - if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static > data member and baseclass component of T is value-initialized
> - **if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;**
> - **otherwise, the object is zero-initialized**
>
> ...
>
> **An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized.**

Comment: Yes, you are right, S is default initialized. That means that the array within is too default initialized,because S is a POD, and default initalization for an array is not the same as zero-initialization

Comment: I am sorry, I hadn't noticed the constructor, and thought this was a POD. Sorry, your answer is correct