# Error Displayed While Printing variable

Tags: c++, user-experience

I wish I knew were the error in this was, but I do not. Here is the class:

```
class Student
{
public:
float grade[10];
float averageGrade;

float average();
Student() : averageGrade(0.0f) {}

};
```

Here is the function:

```
float Student::average()
{ 

    cout << "How many grades would you like to enter? (Up to ten)\n";
    float x;
    cin >> x;

cout << "What is your first grade?";
cin >> grade[0];
for (int i = 1; i < x; i++)
{
cout << "What is the next number?\n";
cin >> grade[i];
}
averageGrade = accumulate(grade, grade+10, 0.0);
averageGrade = averageGrade / x;

return averageGrade;
    }
```

And here is main:

```
    int main()
{
Student s;

s.average();

cout << s.averageGrade;
system ("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

So whenever it outputs s.averageGrade, I just get what looks like a memory address or something. There are no errors when compiling.

Here is the output:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: Weapons, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>weapon.cpp
1>c:\users\hastudent\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\weapons\weapons\weapon.cpp(31) : warning C4244: '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
1>Linking...
1>Embedding manifest...
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\HAStudent\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Weapons\Weapons\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>Weapons - 0 error(s), 1 warning(s)
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: what does accumulate() do? Can you post the source?

Comment: Except for that `system("PAUSE")` -- no idea what's going on there! -- it looks OK to me, should work fine.

Comment: @Kevin -- `accumulate()` is in `<numeric>`, it's part of the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that you pass `grade+10` to accumulate, even if the user does not enter ten records. This may cause accumulate to read junk data, which can have unpredictable effects.

You can fix this by changing x from a float to an int, and changing the accumulate call to `averageGrade = accumulate(grade, grade + x, 0.0);`

Comment: And it's displaying in scientific notation, the "pointer".  Good catch Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out the `averageGrade` member that you never assigned so it has a random value. You want to print the output of the function instead: `std::cout << s.average()`

Comment: He assigns the member and then returns the same.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding `10` numbers even if the user specified less than `10`.

```
averageGrade = accumulate(grade, grade+10, 0.0);
```

This line should be

```
averageGrade = accumulate(grade, grade+x, 0.0);
```

The grade[10] values do not automatically get initialize to `0.0`.

Comment: gah!  I saw that earlier, but assumed he'd default-initialized the array.

Comment: @MooingDuck Thats ok, thanks for your help anyway. What do you mean by default-initialized?

Comment: `Student() : averageGrade(0.0f), grade() {}` which initializes the elements of `grade` to the default value of zero.

Comment: or `float grade[10] = {};` if `grade` were a local variable instead of a member.

Comment: @MooingDuck - Is using `grade()` to initialize the member array in the standard?

Comment: @JohnPS: §8.5/10: `An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (), shall be value-initialized`  I haven't tested it, but I can't find anything in the standard of why it shouldn't apply to arrays too.

Comment: @MooingDuck - Thanks, for some reason I never picked this up. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499263/will-default-constructing-an-integer-array-zero-initialize-it